# "open()" fails in large for loops

Tags: python

I am trying to save ~4 million websites (EDGAR SEC filings) to .txt format. To this end I have a for loop that using selenium in python opens a website, sends crtl+a and crtl+c and copys the text from clipboard into a python string element. This works fine. However, afer - what seem arbirtary intervals - the for loop breaks down, when I try to write the python string into a txt file.

Essentially I am looping such that each loop creates new "text" object (which is str in python).

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=path + '/codes_ml/geckodriver/geckodriver.exe') # initialize driver

for row in range(1,num_urls):
    ticker = fund_reports_table.loc[row,"Ticker"]
    perioddate = fund_reports_table.loc[row,"Perioddater"]
    part = fund_reports_table.loc[row,"Part"]
    report_url = fund_reports_table.loc[row,"URL"]
    nbrparts= fund_reports_table.loc[row,"NbrParts"]
    filingdate = fund_reports_table.loc[row,"Filingdate"]
    driver.get(report_url)
    element = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("body")
    element.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL+'a')
    element.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL+'c')
    text = clipboard.paste()
    filename = ticker + "_" + filingdate + "_" + perioddate + "_" + str(part) + "of" + str(nbrparts) + ".txt"
    os.chdir("E:\\EDGAR_reports")
    output = open(filename, "wb")
    output.write(text.encode('utf-8', errors="ignore"))
    output.close()     
    del output, text, perioddate, part, report_url, nbrparts, filingdate
```

where fund_reports_table is a dataframe with columns as indicated in the first few lines of code. After some thousands files (strange enough it seems to vary with where they are saved to), the following error occurs:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2910, in run_code
exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
File "<ipython-input-4-915577cbb167>", line 21, in <module>
output = open(filename, "wb")
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 
'QILGX_2009-07-29_2009-05-31_1of1.txt'
```

The strange thing is that if I restart the loop (i) the same problem occurs, but (ii) if I change the directory in os.chdir() the code works just fine, i.e. the txt is created exactly as it should.

**It behaves as if there is a maximum number of files in a given folder that python's open() can handle (but I could not find any info on that online)** 
The folder contains 16.378 .txt files consuming 1.7 GB space (created by this very code). There is 40GB space left on this drive. I am running PyCharm with administrator rights, I can manually create new files in the same folder.

Well aware that you cannot recreate the issue with the code/info provided, can anyone point me what to think about? I guess it related to some windows/python interaction, since it works for a couple thousands files and then breaks down.

Comment: Using selenium to scrape the pages is inefficient. Why not use beautiful soup or similar?

Comment: What makes you think that it has to do with the loop or the number of files in the directory and not with what the error message says?

Comment: what your `del` statement supposed to do? `Python` has gc

Comment: try simply `open("E:\\EDGAR_reports\\test", "wb").close()` to check if you have permission to write in given directory

Comment: As far as I'm concerned, I would indeed start with checking the permissions on the file(s) that cause(s) the problem - chances are there already are files by the same name that you don't have the required permissions on.

Comment: wrt/ the " maximum number of files in a given folder that python's open() can handle" thing, it's complete nonsense - if there's a limitation here, it's a filesystem limitation, not a Python one.

Comment: What disk format is used by your E: drive?  If it's FAT32, it has a limit of 64K files per directory - and long filenames (beyond the original 8.3 character limit) are implemented by using additional directory entries.

Comment: @OzzyWalsh: I am trying to parse EDGAR SEC filings (for exmaple this report: https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/766285/000076628509000020/amana-ncsr20090531.htm). Apparently their HTML formatting is poor, such that beaituful soup does not work (According to my collegue who tried for a while). In any case the problem is not related to selenium.

Comment: @marekful: The error indicates that I am lacking some sort of permission to write in this folder. This puzzles me since thousands of files have been created and suddenly the permission is lacking?

Comment: @AzatIbrakov: I agree that this is not necssary. as I couldnt figure out the problem I tried to figure whether maybe something is stored for some reason. If I take the del statement out, nothing changes.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers: I agree that the number is not the problem, I just tried to say "it behaves as if" (by that mean that this error is what I would expect if file number limits or disk space were the problem -- but they are not)

Comment: @SAFEX the error refers to one specific file. Out of tens of thousands you may have a few which for whatever reason ended up not having write permission for the user who runs python.

Comment: @jasonharper, good catch. Indeed both drives where this error occured are FAT32, albeit I am well below 64 files in the directory. Then again maybe the long names cause this problem. I will try this immediatly, and let you know! Thanks!

Comment: LFN support takes up one additional directory entry for each 13 characters in the full filename.  So, your `QILGX_2009-07-29_2009-05-31_1of1.txt`, at 36 characters, eats up 4 entries in total - which turns the 64K limit into 16K actual files that can be stored.

Comment: @jasonharper, I reformatted the drive to NTFS and restarted. So far it broke down somewhere at step 8000, I am now at 10000 and counting, still no error! Thanks so much! I will see whether this just did the trick!

Comment: @marekful: turned out the FAT32 formatting was the issue! thats why changing the directory to save the file in helped!